# How are assets stripped before bankruptcy?

Tags: real-estate, equity, bankruptcy, hedge-funds

[This New Yorker article](https://www.newyorker.com/magazine/2021/06/07/the-death-of-hahnemann-hospital) says

> ...hedge funds and private equity have used leveraged buyouts to
> purchase chains like Sears and Toys R Us, and then stripped their
> assets, including real estate, en route to bankruptcies.
> ...encouraging investors to destroy hospitals that occupy valuable
> land.

How does a firm acquire an entity and transfer out real estate assets without the value of the real estate coming back to the original owner?  For example, how could they buy hospital X, sell or transfer the real estate the hospital sits on, without the value of that real estate ending up on the hospital's books, then declare the hospital bankrupt yet not account for the real estate?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this doesn't appear to be a question about personal finance.

Comment: Why do you think the real estate was not accounted for?

Comment: You wouldn't be able to do that with an historically non-profit hospital (there are paths to for-profitness, but the rules are strict).  If it's a for-profit hospital, then it's about the same as Toys-R-Us or Sears (though you'd get much worse press)

Answer (score 7):

You aquire the equity by buying it using borrowed money.  You can use the equity you're buying as collateral against the loan.

Once you own the business, you can start declaring dividends to yourself.  Any income the company makes is turned into dividends.  Over time, those dividends pay off your loan, but leave the company with no money to re-invest.

One way to get more money to keep the business going is a sell and lease-back arrangement on any real estate the business owns.  Sell the land to a property investment company, and then lease it back from them.  The money raised can be used to keep the business afloat, or to pay more dividends.

Eventually, the company has no assets left, and is running entirely off borrowed money.  It only takes a small drop in sales to drive the company into bankruptcy.  But the venture capitalists don't really care by that point - they have taken out more money from the business than they ever spent buying it.

Answer (score -1):

Imagine a hospital in the middle of a city that sits on a valuable piece of land, like ocean-front in San Francisco or something.

Maybe the hospital earns net revenue of... $10M a year. Maybe the land is worth $100M. The hospital owners would need to operate for 10 years before they 'earn back' the value of the land that they could otherwise sell immediately. Now, historical owners might choose to continue operating a business rather than 'strip it for parts', because of some sort of emotional connection to the business [or perhaps because they never considered such a severe action, or don't foresee the same problems in the business model that downgrade the potential of future revenue]. But a hedge fund that just bought the hospital for $90M might have done so because they know the land is worth $100M. They don't care about the business [in this case a hospital] in particular, they just want to sell the land, liquidate the business, and walk away.

For something like Toys R Us, that can lead to significant long-term problems for laid-off employees, or local economies, or other various impacts. For something like a hospital, that can lead to even more severe outcomes [ultimately this is the simple conclusion of a for-profit healthcare system, that shareholder profit is not the same as 'best-healthcare'].

Comment: This answers "why" but not "how". How do they sell the land for $100 million without the $100 million becoming part of the assets that get distributed in the bankruptcy?

Comment: @ThePhoton What does "bankruptcy" mean? There are different types of bankruptcy, and rules will be different for how pre-bankruptcy assets are viewed. I am not a lawyer, so I can advise on none of that. However I don't think that's where the OP's question came from, the OP seems to think that the hedge fund is cheating the "prior owner" out of something, the act of bankruptcy doesn't really seem to come into play at that level of understanding.

Comment: You could just as easily ask "[how] can a company pay a dividend to shareholders in the same year it declares bankruptcy?" because it is the act of the dividend, not the sale of land, that creates a problem. And that will be a specific set of jurisdictional rules defining when dividends can legally be paid.

Comment: 'Bankruptcy' doesn't even necessarily mean that any lenders got burned, it could be the simplest method of liquidating all remaining assets and liabilities available to the owners after paying out a dividend from the proceeds of sale from the land.

Comment: Those points all seem to me to be more relevant to the question OP asked than what you posted as an answer.